# Using Scala with Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, scala, android-studio

I installed the 1.5.2 Scala plugin in Android Studio 1.2.2.  I have an existing (functioning) project coded in Java.  I added a trivial class in Scala to replace an existing Java class just to try it out.  The IDE seems to validate the Scala code but the reference to the class from the Java code is unresolved.  I don't know why.  I've successfully mixed the languages under SBT on the server side of this project.

The Java code referencing looks like this:

```
package net.from.apprise;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.json.*;
class ItemRelation extends SharableRecord implements Serializable, JSONable  {
    public static final String TAG = "IR";
    String listKey;
    String description;
    String barCode;
    Purch purch;
```

snip...

`Purch` was changed from `Purchase` which is defined in Java and was resolving OK.  The Scala code is:

```
package net.from.apprise

class Purch {
   val whatever:Int = 1
}
```

Attempts to build yield: **error: cannot find symbol class Purch**

The Scala code for the Purch class lives in app/build/main/scala/net.from.apprise directory.  Similarly, the Java source is in app/build/main/java/net.from.apprise.  AS sees the Scala code, and issues errors if there are any.  But no resolution between classes.

Do I need to do something special or am I overlooking something dumb?  Configuration of AS?  Naming convention?

Comment: Not sure how AS handle this this, but isn't the convention to use / instead of . for the actual path? E.g. app/build/main/java/net/from/apprise on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is the convention for Java, although it should not matter for Scala as class definitions can appear anywhere.  And in fact my post above is wrong - the path for the Java (but not the Scala) uses slashes.  AS displays the slashes as "." in the UI for some reason, so I was thrown by that.  I'm going to make it more consistent to see what happens.

Comment: Moved the Scala to app/src/main/scala/net/from/apprise to correspond to Java convention.  No effect.

Comment: class definitions can appear anywhere, but in general you should try to maintain the package structure. Makes it easy for people and tools to find your code. Definitely sounds like a class path issue though. You should check if the relevant .class files were generated in your IDE's output. Perhaps a build/ folder was created? Scala's compiler outputs java bytecode. We can verify whether the function is being created in the first place. If the class file is present, this may indicate a classpath issue at runtime.

Comment: Good point.  Searching the tree reveals that Purch.class, does not appear anywhere.  So I suppose the IDE (I've switched to Intellij 14) is just not compiling it in the first place.

Comment: IntelliJ definitely has good support for scala. I used it for a few years doing scala development. I don't know what your preferred build environment is, but I personally use gradle and import the project from IntelliJ. This yields a reasonable IDE environment and also allows me to ship it to a continuous integration system (e.g. jenkins) to build. Unfortunately, I don't know how good android support for gradle + ide is though. Back to the original message, perhaps java and scala cannot be mixed in the same source tree? They might need to have their own module instead of being mixed.

Comment: I've been advised on IRC to set it all up with SBT and then import it.

Comment: Same approach as importing gradle then. Let us know if it works. :)

Comment: It did not work well.  Probably more of a personality problem than technical, but I'm abandoning an integrated solution for now.  I'm going to package the Scala code into a jar with SBT outside of Intellij.  Then Gradle can pull it in.  Path of least resistance.

Comment: See http://scala-android.org/quickstart/ for some good doc on how to do this.

Answer (score 12):

The [Scala Plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA) for Android Studio or IntelliJ is only a tool for helping you  at writing scala code. It is so smart it makes possible to reference the scala classes from java (and other way around) in IDE, that I think you meant with "IDE seems to validate the Scala code".

If you are developing an android application and you use a gradle build tool then I recommend to you that you use the [Gradle scala plugin](https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin). It is working with official android plugin for gradle.
This plugin is then making instructions for building your scala files into bytecode with .class ending which is used in running application.

Below is how my skeleton gradle file looks like for scala plugin:

```groovy
buildscript {

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // scala from https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin
        classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.4"
    }

}

android { 

    ... 
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"

dependencies {

    ...
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6'
}

// Configuration for scala compiler options as follows
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    // If you want to use scala compile daemon
    scalaCompileOptions.useCompileDaemon = true
    // Suppress deprecation warnings
    scalaCompileOptions.deprecation = false
    // Additional parameters
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-feature"]
}
```

And .java and .scala files can be mixed in the same project directory, as in:

```
app/java/com.example
  /ItemRelation.java
  /Purch.scala
```

Comment: Can you still separate the Scala and Java files though? As in `app/java/com.example/ItemRelation.java` and `app/scala/com.example/Purch.scala`?

Answer (score 2):

when you follow @Renatol steps (which is great), you will encounter an error :

```
Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultScalaSourceSet(java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.BaseDirFileResolver)
```

so take a look at this answer to continue the process :

[gradle-android-scala-plugin gives "Could not find matching constructor" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797662/gradle-android-scala-plugin-gives-could-not-find-matching-constructor-error)