# What is the simplest way to mix Java+Scala in an Android project using Gradle?

Tags: android, scala, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What is the simplest way to mix Java+Scala in an Android project using Gradle ?

Is it using https://github.com/saturday06/gradle-android-scala-plugin ?

I am asking this because examples in `gradle-android-scala-plugin` [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797662/gradle-android-scala-plugin-gives-could-not-find-matching-constructor-error) and I don't know how to get started, maybe there is some other easy way to mix Scala+Java ?

Is there any simpler (less painful, buggy) way than the `gradle-android-scala-plugin` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good solution using gradle.

Use sbt-android instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that using sbt doesn't mean you can't use android studio. You can import sbt projects into android studio with the scala plugin. (however, current version has a bug that will be fixed shortly)

Comment: Nice, how about wysiwyg editing of gui layout files ?

Comment: Wysiwyg isn't a thing on android. Regardless of the availability of the designer, it's basically garbage.

Comment: Interesting, so pros don't use it ? Only beginners?

Answer (score 1):

Use Android studio 3.3.2 and create Android project.

Write this code in build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.github.AllBus:gradle-android-scala-plugin:3.3.2'
    }
}
```

and add app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ...

}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12"
    ...

}
```