# Scala with android studio

Tags: java, scala, android-studio

I have a project in Java with Android studio 3.2, and I want to add some Scala files.
I have already read this [Using Scala with Java in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874693/using-scala-with-java-in-android-studio)
and I have some questions about it.

From what I understand, when you want to have java and scala files, it's better to use the gradle scala plugin instead of the scala plugin.
But because the topic is rather old, I was wondering if it's still true, or if I should use the scala plugin.

Thanks for the answers and any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I create fork this plugin https://github.com/AllBus/gradle-android-scala-plugin
This version of the plugin supports Android 28 and Gradle 5.3

write this code in build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.github.AllBus:gradle-android-scala-plugin:3.3.2'
    }
}
```

and add app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ...

}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12"
    ...

}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.